# OpenGL LWJGL re-sizable textured cube

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl, cube

I'm trying to make a method that will draw a cube with a specified size and texture. Problem is, when I resize the cube, the texture isn't resizing along with it. For example, if I draw with size .5F, only 8x8 pixels of a 16x16 texture draw. What am I doing wrong?

```
static void drawCube(float size, Texture tex, int x, int y, int z) {
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTranslatef(x, y, z);

    tex.bind();
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0f * size, 0.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f * size, -1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0f * size, 0.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(1.0f * size, -1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(1.0f * size, 1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f * size, 1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0f * size, 0.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f * size, -1.0f * size, -1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f * size, 1.0f * size, -1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(1.0f * size, 1.0f * size, -1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0f * size, 0.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(1.0f * size, -1.0f * size, -1.0f * size);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f * size, 1.0f * size, -1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0f * size, 0.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f * size, 1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0f * size, 0.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(1.0f * size, 1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(1.0f * size, 1.0f * size, -1.0f * size);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f * size, -1.0f * size, -1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(1.0f * size, -1.0f * size, -1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0f * size, 0.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(1.0f * size, -1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0f * size, 0.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f * size, -1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0f * size, 0.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(1.0f * size, -1.0f * size, -1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(1.0f * size, 1.0f * size, -1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(1.0f * size, 1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0f * size, 0.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(1.0f * size, -1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glEnd();


    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0f * size, 0.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f * size, -1.0f * size, -1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0f * size, 0.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f * size, -1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f * size, 1.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0f * size, 1.0f * size);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f * size, 1.0f * size, -1.0f * size);
    glEnd();

    glTranslatef(-x, -y, -z);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The texture coordinates always use a [0..1] coordinate system. If you want to draw the full texture, don't scale the texture coordinates according to the size, ie

```
glTexCoord2d(1.0f * size, 0.0f * size); // Not good! (For this purpose anyway)
glTexCoord2d(1.0f, 0.0f); // Good!
```